Recover deprecated MS-hosted images
I am trying to get access to the vs2015-win2012r2 image (which was deprecated as a MS-hosted agent in 2020) in the Runner images github repo in order to create from it a self-hosted agent, but seems it is not available.
I tried to going backwards in history till 2020 but seems that these commits are gone.
Any way to recover this image?
Thanks in advance

Could you please edit your question and include your requirements for a self-hosted Windows agent? Which tools/versions do you need to install? .NET Framework xxx, ...?

Hi @RuiJarimba, the problem is not creating a self-hosted windows agent with specific tools/versions, the problem is knowing what tools/versions were used. We have some older applications that were built with that agent and some modifications are required, we would like to use exactly the same configuration for building this modifications.

Try asking in the Developer Community.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Recover-deprecated-MS-hosted-images/10815521?q=Recover+deprecated+MS-hosted+images Not too much help, at the moment...
